# room databae: when i click on the save button, it works fine! but the problem is to i have to restart the app then i can only see data on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-room

When I click on the save button data is stored but the problem is I have to give restart my android app on a mobile device then when I got back data shows on `RecyclerView`. Here's my code

**Main Activity**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etFirstname, etLastname;
    Button btnSave;
    AppDatabase database;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "userdb").allowMainThreadQueries().build();

        etFirstname = findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);
        etLastname = findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);

        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String fName = etFirstname.getText().toString();
                String lName = etLastname.getText().toString();

                if (fName.isEmpty() || lName.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please enter data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setFirstName(fName);
                    user.setLastName(lName);

                    database.dao().addUser(user);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        adapter = new UserAdapter(database.dao().getUsers());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**Adapter class**

```java
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<User> users;

    public UserAdapter(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_list_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewFirst.setText(users.get(position).firstName);
        holder.textViewLast.setText(users.get(position).lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }
    
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewFirst, textViewLast;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewFirst = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
            textViewLast = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, when you save, you need to fetch again from db and load it to recyclerview

Comment: okay thanks but how to do that??

Comment: should i make new method reloaduser in recyclerview ??

Comment: once you save, if it is successful then query the db, get the list and supply the new list to adapter and notify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter requires a list of users `List<User> users`, and you pass that only once when you create the activity, but you don't update that list after you load it the first time. onCreate activates only once, and creates a click listener for the button, it's your duty to update and add to the existing list after that.

Try doing this:
Since your user list in the adapter is private, create a function to add a new user in the existing list, something like this:

```
public void add(User user) {
    users.add(user);
    notifyItemInserted(users.size() - 1);
}
```

Try adding `adapter.add(user)`in the end of the else block from `btnSave.onClickListener`

Just to explain, `notifyItemInserted` notifies the recyclerView about a new item, at the last position of the list, so it can refresh the data

Comment: what is mc?? in users.add(mc) --->>> what is mc??

Comment: I apologize, that's meant to be user

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the error pointed out that you are not updating your data. One other solution to do away with you manually updating is to use `LiveData` instead.
It will take care of the data changes. Below is a great guide on using `Room` with `LiveData`

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#6

Comment: i don't want to use livedata please care to give short solution cause now i know that i am making mistake in adapter class i think i have to add reload user method and call it in the last of add user holder